# google keep: "Starting on December 5, 2022​, notes created here will not save automatically..."

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, google-keep

I use the chrome extension for Google Keep whenever I want to save something to look up later. Lately, I get a weird message when I save something to google keep using the extension. It says:

> Starting on December 5, 2022​, notes created here will not save
> automatically. You will also have to access and edit existing notes
> associated with a URL via Keep

Here's what it looks like...

[image: weird message I get when saving to google keep]

**It is utterly unclear what this means to me!** Is it trying to say that the chrome extension for google keep will stop working? Why is it phrased like that? Why don't they just say that the extension is being removed? Is that what they mean? If not, then what?

Also, what do they mean "automatically"? I am not saving links to Google Keep "automatically", I am clicking on the extension's icon and then editing the title and/or note and applying a tag. How is that "automatic"?

Then, it says that I "also" have to go directly to keep. Why "also"? What are they trying to say?

Comment: See https://support.google.com/docs/thread/186295588/can-you-elaborate-on-the-announcement-on-achange-in-google-keep-as-of-december-5-2022?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

From
[Can you elaborate on the announcement on a change in Google Keep as of December 5, 2022](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/186295588?hl=en&msgid=187584668),
an answer relayed from the Google team was as follows :

> On December 5th, Google Notes will stop auto-saving. The change is that there will be a save button, and you will have to click the save button. If you click on the Chrome extension, it will only let you create a note; it won’t recall an existing note associated with that URL. You will have to go to Google Keep on the web (keep.google.com) or the app to see and edit that note.

Comment: Thanks! I see now, but it doesn't make any sense. Why would someone click on the google-keep extension icon if they didn't also want to save? Perhaps to review what they put in previously, but that's *also* going away. It seems like they're stripping out functionality from the extension for no apparent reason. Is keep being abused somehow and this is the reaction?

Comment: Google changes don't always make sense. Some genius decided on this change, perhaps because demanding a login to `keep.google.com` is better for security.